# Drop a message Kafka Streams Topology

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

I would like to know if there is a way to drop a record/message from a stream Topology?

I have a setup like the following:

```
 builder.stream("my-source-topic")
                .map(CustomMapper)
                .mapValues(CustomValueMapper)
                .filterNot(CustomFilter)
                .transformValues(CustomValueTransformer)
                .toStream()
```

Each CustomMapper/CustomFilter etc overrides their respective apply/transform methods they could look like the following, as noted the error might be unrecoverable and this is an ok solution these messages will be handled manually and a respective log is written.
Assuming the unrecoverable error happens during the first map how do i now prevent the later Stages from even processing the record, i would like to stop the processing of this record and move to the next record.

```
@Override
    public V transform(K readOnlyKey, V value) {
        try {
        // do some logic
        } catch(Exception e){
            // process error - this might be unrecoverable.
            
            dropRecord(); // this is what i would be looking for if possible
        }
    }
```

I could kill the thread and have a customUncaughtExceptionHandler reschedule the thread which would not commit the offset and therefor try to process the faulty record again.

Creating a wrapper for the objects passed would require to add a check in each proccessing step to see if the record is still valid.

Adding a .branch() before each processing step to would also require a decent amount of rework.

Comment: You could have the map add an 'invalid' flag to its output and have a simple filter after the map that filters out those objects.

Comment: Yes but i would have to add the filter after every processing step, i would also have to create a wrapper class that contains a field to be marked as invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You can drop a message in a `Transformer` simply by returning `null`. See the Javadoc of [Transformer#transform](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/965ec40c0a282bc311c702c6eb795689ec7ddfa5/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Transformer.java#L78).
So your example would be:

```java
    @Override
    public V transform(K readOnlyKey, V value) {
        try {
        // do some logic
        } catch(Exception e){
            // process error - this might be unrecoverable.
            
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Note, that you can do this currently only in a `Transformer`, but not in a `ValueTransformer`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for posting a helpful answer!